# Tikz tree family tree spacing and lines

Tags: tikz-trees, trees, genealogy

I'm stuck on the problem of making a family tree which has parents linked by a line with children centered underneath, with some spouses having their parentage also indicated. I've tried two methods, one via co-ordinates and one via trees.

Co-ordinates is definite but tricky at the scale of diagram I am trying to achieve, and will quickly grow very complex. It also is not easy to adjust if later additions need to be made. In these regards trees are much much easier, but the limitation is that they seem always to grow down from one node.

I also included a picture I made by moving things around in paint to show what I am trying to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (Albert) at (-1, 5) {Albert};
\node (Barbara) at (1, 5) {Barbara};
\node (AlBa) at (0, 5) {};
\draw[-] (Albert) -- (Barbara);
\node (Charlie) at (0, 4) {Charlie};
\draw[-] (AlBa) -- (Charlie);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={sibling distance=3cm},level 2/.style={sibling distance=1.5cm}]
    \node {Albert --- Barbara}[edge from parent fork down]
        child {node {Charlie}}
        child {node {Derek}}
        child {node {~~~~~~~~~Edgar---Frances}  
            child {node {~~~~~~~George---Helen}
                child {node {India}}
            }
        }           
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: example family tree]

Comment: I once thought about creating a hyperlinked family tree, with one page for each individual, containing parents and all their spouses and offspring with linkis to each.

Comment: Maybe the [familytree package](https://ctan.org/pkg/familytree) can help you.

Comment: https://ctan.org/topic/genealogy (includes the familytree @FaustoMauricioLagosSuárez mentioned and also genealogytree, which I've seen used on this site).